# How does this instruction format limit the number of memory addresses?

Tags: computer-architecture

I have come across a question like this. And I don't have any idea how to solve this.

> Suppose a machine with instruction format of the form `opcode A,B,R` where `A` and `B` are main memory addresses and `R` is a register. If there are 20 registers in the machine, how many addresses are possible to have in the main memory? An instruction occupies 32 bits and the instruction set has 32 opcodes.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: How many bits will you need to encode the 32 op codes? How many bits will you need to encode the 20 registers? Then, how many bits are left in the instruction code to encode each of the two memory addresses? If you have $n$ address bits for a memory address, how many memory addresses are possible?

Comment: What do you think? Surely you do have *any* thoughts on this?

Comment: @RickDecker:thanks for the points you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of my friend have managed to solve this one.

20 registers need 5 bits.
32 opcodes needs 5 bits.

therefore remaining bits for main memory=32-5-5
                                        =22
there are two locations in the  instruction.
so, bits for memeory location = 22/2=11

so, total memory locations = 2^11=2048

reason to get the 5 bits: to represent 20 registers you need at least 5 bits.it means 2^5 = 32.

Comment: Well ... the reason you need 5 bits to address the register is that 4 bits (or less) give you at most 16 differents values (or less) which is not enough to distinguish 20 registers. But 5 bits (or more) give you at least 32 values, which is enough. You should try to stick to full sentences, and proper syntax, including the use of capital letters. Writing well will help you to think well. Complete reasonning (as I did for your last sentence) will help you too.